# where in clause in nested query

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, where-clause, clause

I am using mysql and php. I am unable to delete any records even if records exist to meet the condition specified in the query , please help to identify the problem, 
my query is

Table1 (id, LName)
table2(id,LName)

```
delete from table1 where Lname in (select Lname from table2);
```

Comment: This is not a good style to ask questions in SO. Please show your table structure and what you have done so far.

Comment: I have two tables table1(id, name ) and table2(id, name), i want to delete records from table1 if it same name exist in table2.

Comment: Please add the table description and other details in your comment itself.

Comment: Your query seems to be ok. What problem did you encounter?

Comment: Are you getting any error or just a `0 rows modified` warning.

Comment: Is Lname a typo? Your tables seem to have a column called name

Comment: I m getting  0 row(s)affected) message

Comment: yes Lname is varchar type

Comment: show examples of your data

Answer (score 2):

`delete from table1 where Lname in (select Lname from table2);`

Its Work for me. Maybe it have case problem so try like this

`delete from table1 where upper(Lname) in (select upper(Lname) from table2);`

Answer (score 0):

According to the table structure you provided in your comment, the query should be somewhat like this:

```
delete from table1
where name in 
(select name 
 from table2)
```

But according to your question, it seems your table don't seem to have a column named 'Lname'.

If your column name is actually 'Lname', then the query can be re-written as:

```
delete from table1
where Lname in 
(select Lname 
 from table2)
```

Please, please be extra careful mentioning table structure, you MUST post the appropriate name of your tables and columns, and with correct spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a JOIN:-

```
DELETE table1
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.Lname table2.Lname
```

but your original SQL should work